# Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку тире

Tags: пунктуация, бессоюзное

> 1 Вы проходите мимо дерева — оно не шелохнется: оно нежится (Тургенев)
>
> 2 Дуб держится — к земле Тростиночка припала (Кр.)

1 предложение) нет идей. Мне кажется, должна стоять запятая вместо дефиса.

2 предложение) "если во 2 части содержится резкое противопоставление по отношению к содержанию — ставится дефис". А где здесь противопоставление?

Comment: Это не дефис, это тире. Дефис используют внутри слова, например "как-нибудь", "по-английски" и т.д.

Comment: _Рустам Мулюков: "если во 2 части содержится резкое противопоставление по отношению к содержанию - ставится **дефис**"_ === Гм... Это какой же источник Вы цитируете? В обоих приведённых Вами предложениях употреблены не дефисы. а **тире**.

Comment: Виноват! Я неправильно процитировал учебник. Неграмотный я =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) *Хороши летние туманные дни, хотя охотники их и не любят. 
В такие дни нельзя стрелять: птица, выпорхнув у вас из-под ног, мигом,тотчас же исчезает в беловатой мгле неподвижного тумана.*

*Но как тихо, как невыразимо тихо всё кругом! Всё проснулось и всё молчит. **Вы проходите мимо дерева – оно не шелохнётся: оно нежится.***

Да, непростое предложение. Во-первых, где же здесь неожиданное присоединение, указание на быструю смену событий, как говорит Розенталь.  Нет здесь ничего такого, разве не видно?

**Это сопоставление:** *Вы проходите, а оно не шелохнётся*. Или это **временные отношения**: *Когда вы проходите, то оно не шелохнется*. В обоих случаях надо ставить тире.

**И куда же пропало двоеточие?** Не вписался тургеневский знак в учебные правила, вот его и опустили.

Тире и двоеточие в коротком предложении и правда смотрятся необычно. Можно, конечно, поставить **запятую**.  Тогда предложения станут однородными с перечислительной интонацией: *оно не шелохнется, оно нежится.*

Но Тургенев выбрал другой вариант: **двоеточие у него действительно обозначает причину,** а в устной речи — увеличенную паузу. Почему не шелохнется? **Ну конечно же, оно нежится.**

2) Дуб держится — к земле //Тростиночка припала.

**И где же здесь противопоставление?** При противопоставлении события исключают друг друга, противоречат друг другу.

У нас же пропущен **сопоставительный союз  А.** Сопоставляются обычно предметы и ситуации из одного ряда, которые чем-то различаются. В данном случае налетела буря, которую по-разному переносят дуб и тростиночка.

И мое пожелание вам, дорогие участники форума: **будьте внимательны к русскому языку, не относитесь к нему формально.**

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon! Я удивлен (в хорошем смысле слова!), что Вам удается чувствовать язык так легко! Я читаю учебное пособие по русскому языку для школьников старших классов и поступающих в вузы (2010 г.). Наверное, нужно смотреть в "Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация". В уч. пособии Розенталь упоминает вскользь про сопоставление (я ничего не понял оттуда про сопоставление). В справочнике же я нашел и упоминаемый **союз но и союз а**, упоминаемый V. Lilla. Этого упоминания в уч. пособии не было =\

Answer (score 3):

1. В бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, перед второй частью ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится неожиданное присоединение, указание на быструю смену событий:
   *Вы проходите мимо дерева — оно не шелохнётся, оно нежится* (Т.).
   (Двоеточия перед вторым "оно" в справочнике Розенталя нет — стоит запятая. Это странно, потому что у [Тургенева](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WdgsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT366&lpg=PT366&dq=%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=L7UM1FScpk&sig=ACfU3U37HloUz5EGsDHgOVz2M8EMVF6Q9g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieh6Cgqb7jAhXFJVAKHd-NBW4Q6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false) двоеточие присутствует.)
2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз *но* или *а*):
   *Дуб держится — к земле тростиночка припала* (Кр.).
   (["Дуб и трость"](http://scanpoetry.ru/poetry/5908) — "Тростиночка" с большой буквы.)

[§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=311) (Д. Э. Розенталь)

Comment: V. Lilla, спасибо! 2 пример понял. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в 1 примере нет двоеточия? Разве зависимая часть "оно нежится" не является причиной главной части "оно не шелохнется"? Я не понимаю. ;(

Comment: _Рустам Мулюков: Разве зависимая часть "оно нежится" не является причиной главной части "оно не шелохнется"?_ === Конечно является. И двоеточие вполне обоснованно.

Comment: Не знаю, как ответить правильно: пока дополняла ответ (текст + ссылка)  — задали вопрос. Куда писать?

Comment: _V. Lilla: Не знаю, как ответить правильно: пока дополняла ответ (текст + ссылка) — задали вопрос. Куда писать?_ === Самым, на мой взгляд, правильным решением для Вас было бы ещё раз исправить свой ответ. Ведь Вы же в нём написали по поводу тургеневского тире двоеточия: "Это странно". А ничего странного в двоеточии нет.

Comment: Я имела в виду вот это: странно, что у Розенталя нет двоеточия в предложении, а у Тургенева-то оно как раз есть. И по правилам, я думаю, должно быть.